# Assign static Mask on moving Surface with PyGame

Tags: python, pygame, mask, pygame-surface

I just began my first PyGame project yesterday, and I can't find how to properly use Mask entity to apply on a moving Surface.

I made a specific class for animated Surfaces

```
class LabelObject():
    def __init__(self, surface, x, y, endX, speed, idleTime):
        self.surface = surface
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.endX = endX
        self.speed = speed
        self.idleTime = idleTime
        self.alpha = 255
        self.timer_start = 0
        self.timer_end = 0
        self.pos = self.surface.get_rect(x=self.x,y=self.y)

    def move(self):
        self.timer_start += 1
        if self.timer_start > self.idleTime:
            if self.pos.right > self.endX:
                self.pos.x += self.speed
            elif self.pos.x < self.x:
                self.timer_end += 1
                if self.timer_end > self.idleTime:
                    self.alpha -= 25
                if self.timer_end > self.idleTime + 11:
                    self.pos = self.surface.get_rect(x=self.x, y=self.y)
                    self.timer_start = 0
                    self.timer_end = 0
                    self.alpha = 255
        self.surface.set_alpha(self.alpha)
```

The point of this class is to check if the surface exceeds a given area, and slide to the left to be able to read entirely the text rendered inside it.

In my main loop, I just can blit it to screen like this

```
label = LabelObject(textSurface,20,10,100,-0.5,30)
while not over:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT
             over = True
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    label.move()
    screen.blit(label.surface, label.pos)
    pygame.display.update()
```

This works fine, but I need to apply a mask on it which doesn't have to move. For this example, the Rect of the mask will be `(20, 10, 100-20, label.surface.get_height())`. I see some examples about Mask in the web, but I didn't find the way to use it when the mask is static and the surface is moving.

**EDIT:** I tried using area option in blit function, but there's something strange, the area and the Surface movement are not synchronized.

**EDIT2:** Finally here is the good blit function with area option. Just need to make the blit with static position, and the area with animated position:

```
self.screen.blit(label.surface, (label.x,label.y), area=pygame.Rect(label.x-label.pos.x, 0, label.endX-label.x, label.surface.get_height()))
```

Comment: if you have `self.pos` (`pygame.Rect` instance) then you don't need `self.x` and `self.y` because you have `self.pos.x`, `self.pos.y`, `self.pos.width`, `self.pos.right` (instead of `self.pos[0]+self.pos[2]`), `self.pos.center`, etc. You can use `get_rect(x=self.x, y=self.y)` in place of  `get_rect().move(self.x, self.y)`

Comment: you can use `self.pos.x += self.speed` in place of `self.pos = self.pos.move(self.speed, 0)`

Comment: @furas thank you for your comments, I will clarify my class with your piece of advice.

Comment: maybe you need `pygame.Surface.subsurface(offset_x,....)` with `offset_x += speed` to get part of full image

Comment: I edited my question, I tested area option from blit function, which could be a good way to do it too, but the area and the surface movement are not sync. The area is moving to left too, but slower than the Surface. It's strange because the x position of the area is related to the moving x position of the surface...

Comment: I think blit position should be always the same and only area have to change. I try to make some example to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to do full working example with `subsurface` to cut off visible part of full image. Rect (sub_image_rect) is always the same - to draw in the same place. I only change  offset to cut off different part of image.

I use text and font to generate some image - and everyone can run it without own images.

```
import pygame

# --- constants ---

BLACK = (  0,  0,  0)
RED   = (255,  0,  0)

# --- classes ---

class Label():

    def __init__(self, text, x, y, width):

        font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 35)

        # generate full image
        self.image = font.render(text, True, RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=x, y=y)

        self.width = width
        self.speed = 1

        # offset of visible part
        self.offset_x = 0
        self.max_offset_x = self.rect.width - self.width

        # visible part of image
        self.sub_image = self.image.subsurface((self.offset_x,0), (self.width, self.rect.height))
        self.sub_image_rect = self.sub_image.get_rect(x=x, y=y)


    def move(self):

        # change offset
        self.offset_x += self.speed

        # change move direction
        if self.offset_x < 0:
            self.offset_x = 0
            self.speed = -self.speed
        elif self.offset_x > self.max_offset_x:
            self.offset_x = self.max_offset_x
            self.speed = -self.speed

        print self.offset_x, self.max_offset_x
        # visible part of image
        self.sub_image = self.image.subsurface((self.offset_x, 0),(self.width, self.rect.height))

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.sub_image, self.sub_image_rect)

# --- main ---

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

label = Label("Hello World of Python and Pygame!", 100, 100, 200)

# --- mainloop ---

fps = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

while running:

    # --- events ---

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key ==  pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

    # --- updates ---

    label.move()

    # --- draws ---

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    label.draw(screen)

    fps.tick(25)
    pygame.display.flip()

# --- the end ---

pygame.quit()
```

**EDIT:** I made example with `area` in `blit`. I changed only 3 lines - see `# changed` in code

```
import pygame

# --- constants ---

BLACK = (  0,  0,  0)
RED   = (255,  0,  0)

# --- classes ---

class Label():

    def __init__(self, text, x, y, width):

        font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 35)

        # generate full image
        self.image = font.render(text, True, RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=x, y=y)

        self.width = width
        self.speed = 1

        # offset of visible part
        self.offset_x = 0
        self.max_offset_x = self.rect.width - self.width

        # visible part of image as 'rect' - 'width' is always the same
        self.sub_image_rect = self.image.get_rect(x=0, width=self.width) # changed

    def move(self):

        # change offset
        self.offset_x += self.speed

        # change move direction
        if self.offset_x < 0:
            self.offset_x = 0
            self.speed = -self.speed
        elif self.offset_x > self.max_offset_x:
            self.offset_x = self.max_offset_x
            self.speed = -self.speed

        # visible part of image - change only `x` 
        self.sub_image_rect.x = self.offset_x  # changed

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect, area=self.sub_image_rect)  # changed

# --- main ---

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

label = Label("Hello World of Python and Pygame!", 100, 100, 200)

# --- mainloop ---

fps = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

while running:

    # --- events ---

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key ==  pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

    # --- updates ---

    label.move()

    # --- draws ---

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    label.draw(screen)

    fps.tick(25)
    pygame.display.flip()

# --- the end ---

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I accept your answer, even if I finally used area option. It's always nice to know several ways to do something. For the area you was right too, I just had to replace `label.pos.x` by `label.x` to make blit static, and that works like a charm. Thank you again ;)

Comment: I made example with `area` too - because I have never used `area` before.

Comment: Yeah, thank you, if you want to see my "rough" code it's on Github ;) https://github.com/jbltx/PyAudioTFT